# How to print columns with delimeters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a script to do following

```
while not end of file
read line
print columns 1 to o-1 with | as delimiter
print column o
print columns o+1 to n with | as delimiter
end loop
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each line is simply a list of white-space delimited fields:

```
o=7   # or whatever o should be
while read -r -a columns; do
( IFS="|"
  printf "${columns[*]:0:o-1}\n"
  printf "${columns[o-1]}\n"
  printf "${columns[*]:o}\n"
)
done
```

`read -a` reads the line into an array called `columns`. I put the `printf`s in a subshell so that we don't have to worry about restoring the value of `IFS` later. The syntax `"${array[*]:x:y}"` says to create a string consisting of `y` fields from `array`, starting with field `x`, using the first character of `$IFS` to separate each field in the string.

Comment: what if it is comma (,) seperated?

Comment: @chandan; then you change IFS to be , instead of |

Comment: if the input file is comma separated, use `while IFS=, read -ra columns; do`

Answer (score 0):

if your fields are tab separated the following one line script could print a table with cell borders

```
sed -e 's/\t/_|/g' table.txt |  column -t -s '_' | awk '1;!(NR%1){print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------";}'

Description            |value                 |Comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Internal               |322                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
External               |42515                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For delimiters other than space change \t on the sed command above.